# It's time to adopt Java EE 7 with Java 8 for new enterprise applications?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Java 8 and Java EE 7 seems a great choice for new enterprise applications. However, only GlassFish 4, Wildfly and another one JAS is full profile certified.

So, Is Java EE 7, with Java 8, mature enough for new enterprise applications or it's better maintain Java EE 6 with Java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle removed commercial support from GlassFish and so now it can not be deployed in production. WildFly is under active development and will be commercially supported with JBoss EAP 7 next year. JEUS is only Developer Preview at this time.

I'm seeing lot of Java EE 7 developments/deployments using WildFly, at least they can purchase commercial support when its available. Read more about a state of the Java EE 7 ecosystem at:

http://www.slideshare.net/arungupta1/java-ee-7-soup-to-nuts-at-javaone-2014

Also ready about real-life deployments of Java EE 7 at:

http://www.slideshare.net/arungupta1/lessons-learned-from-realworld-deployments-of-java-ee-7-at-javaone-2014

Both GlassFish and WildFly can run with JDK 8.

For the record, there is no such thing as "full profile". Its either Web Profile or Full Platform.